# How do I output the index of the first repeat number in an array of randomly generated integers (C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C, which will generate 50 random integers between 0-99, then print out or throw to a variable at what index the first repeat number occurs.  I figured using an array would be the best way to go about this.  I seem to be successfully generating an array of random(random enough for this purpose) integers and throwing them into an array.

However, I'm having trouble with my for loops when comparing each element of the array.  It looks like I end up comparing index 1 with index 1 and getting a match.
Here is my current code for reference.  Any help/suggestions would be really appreciated - I'm a programming newbie :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
//define the test pool(N - people in the birthday problem)
//and possible unique attributes(M - birthdays in the birthday problem)
int N = 50;
int M = 100;
int i;
int x;
int y;
int arr[N];
int count = 1;

//use for loop to populate an array of length N with numbers ranging
//from 0 to 99
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
                arr[i] = rand() % (M-1);
                printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
        }

//just formatting the output a little
printf("\n\n\n");


//iterate through the array at each position, comparing it to all other
//positions in the array.  if array[x] does not equal array[y] increment
//the counter.  if it does match, print the counter to the screen.
for(x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
                for(y = 0; y < N; y++)
                        {
                                if(arr[x] != arr[y])
                                        {
                                                count++;
                                        }
                                else
                                        {
                                                printf("the first repeat is  at:  ");
                                                printf("%d\n", count);
                                                break;
                                        }
                                break;
                        }
                break;
        }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `int main()` was fashionable circa 1984.  Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
 for(y = 0; y < N; y++)
```

to

```
 for(y = x + 1; y < N; y++)
```

because, when you choose an element `x`, you have to search for its duplicate in the remaining array *ahead* of `x`, hence, `y=x+1` to `N`. If you again begin searching for the duplicate from `y=0`, you will eventually find `x`'s duplicate at `x` or before.

## A better way:

In your implementation, you had to run two loops to check the duplicate. A faster way would be to record the count of each number occured in a `counter` array, and running only a single loop, check if `counter[ arr[i] ] > 1`, that means the element `arr[i]` has been repeated atleast once.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
//define the test pool(N - people in the birthday problem)
//and possible unique attributes(M - birthdays in the birthday problem)
        int N = 50;
        int M = 100;
        int i;
        int x;
        int y;
        int arr[N];
        //Counter[M] will store the number of occurences
        //of M in the program;
        int counter[M];
        int count = 1;

        for(int i = 0;i < 100; ++i)
        {
                counter[i] = 0;
        }
//use for loop to populate an array of length N with numbers ranging
//from 0 to 99
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
                arr[i] = rand() % (M-1);
                printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
                counter[arr[i]]++; 
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Incrementing the count array
                //of the particular element arr[i].
        }

//just formatting the output a little
        printf("\n\n\n");


//iterate through the array at each position, comparing it to all other
//positions in the array.  if array[x] does not equal array[y] increment
//the counter.  if it does match, print the counter to the screen.
        for(x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
                if (counter[arr[x]] > 1)
                {
                        printf("the first repeat is  at:  ");
                        if (youWantTheIndex)
                        {
                            printf("%d\n", x); //This prints the index
                        }
                        else if (youWantTheElement)
                        {
                        printf("%d\n", arr[x]); //This prints the element.
                        }
                        break;
                }
        }
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in second for loop change `y=0` to `y=x+1`

since your using 0 index for both it is comparing same element so better you increase the index of second element by 1.

it will work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to akaElement's answer you will also need to output "y" as the index and not count because you do not reset count variable, it keeps on incrementing for all the outer loops.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the use of `count` is unclear as it doesn't represent the element where the first duplicate occurs. Rather it represents the sum of unequal tests performed up to the point of the first match. One use of a variable to mark the first match would be as a flag used to stop iteration without a daisy chain of `break`, `break`, etc... It also simplifies the loop logic a bit.

```
    int count = 0;
    ...
    for (x = 0; x < N && count == 0; x++) {
        for (y = x+1; y < N; y++) {
            if (arr[x] == arr[y]) {
                count++;
                printf (" the first repeat is at:  %d & %d  (%d)\n\n", x, y, arr[x]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here you would think of `count` more as `found` than an actual index count. Formatted as shown, you receive the index information of first duplicate along with the duplicate value:

```
 the first repeat is at:  1 & 39  (43)
```

Comment: Thanks David!  I think I have it close to working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach to solve your problem.
here, i took an example where the array is 5 elements, but you can change that with you randomly filled array which you already have.

```
 int main() {
        int N = 5;
        int arr[5] = {1,2,3,1,2};
        for(int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
                if(arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                    printf("first repeat of arr[%d]=%d is at index %d\n", i,arr[i],j);
                    break;//return to the outter loop
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Notice: the inner loop starts from the next index where the outter loop points, so you don't compare the same number with itself.
Also, notice that the outter loop ends at N-2, which is equivalent to `i<N-1`
thats because you dont want to read from illegal cell, since the inner loops starts from `i+1`